# CLOCK timestamp field in clocktable

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

Given the following org data :

```
* PROJECT NAME
** task 1
  CLOCK: [2016-03-21 Mon 09:50]--[2016-03-21 Mon 10:03] =>  0:13
my comment on task1
** task 2                               
mycomment on task2
  CLOCK: [2016-03-21 Mon 11:00]--[2016-03-21 Mon 12:00] =>  1:00
** task 3                                
  CLOCK: [2016-03-22 Tue 12:00]--[2016-03-22 Tue 13:30] =>  1:30
my comment on task3
```

I would like to have a clocktable with "CLOCKED" timestamps, such as this :

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable  :scope file :block month :timestamp t
| Timestamp                                      | Headline     | Time   |      |
|------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------|
|                                                | *Total time* | *2:43* |      |
|------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------|
|                                                | PROJECT NAME | 2:43   |      |
| [2016-03-21 Mon 10:50]--[2016-03-21 Mon 11:03] | \_  task 1   |        | 0:13 |
| [2016-03-21 Mon 11:00]--[2016-03-21 Mon 12:00] | \_  task 2   |        | 1:00 |
| [2016-03-22 Tue 12:00]--[2016-03-22 Tue 13:30] | \_  task 3   |        | 1:30 |
#+END
```

The problem : `timestamp :t` in the clocktable command looks for

> SCHEDULED, DEADLINE, TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP_IA, in this order (as per the manual)

Not for `CLOCK`.

**How can I get the clock data inside the clocktable?**

Formulas obviously come to mind, but could not find one to do the trick. [Special properties](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html) don't do the trick either. I'm stuck.

Thanks !